# Install NPM Packages with dependencies as .tgz

Tags: npm, npm-install

How can I install NPM packages with dependencies as .tgz file?

For example, I want to perform this action on https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-offline-packager

Comment: any luck yet?I might be looking for something similar

Comment: @Immanuel You can use npm pack <package-name>, it will download the package as tgz

Answer (score 0):

You can use `curl` to install any package from `npm` registry using this command

`curl -o package-name.tgz https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash/-/lodash-4.17.21.tgz`

You can specify the version number as in the above example `4.17.21`.